# ¿Cómo creo la función donde mi tiempo limite se agreguen otros 5 minutos después de que alguien oferte algo en los últimos 5 minutos?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, datetimepicker

Necesito crear esta función, una subasta que tiene un límite de tiempo cuando le faltan 5 minutos para acabar, entonces un postor hace una oferta y se agregan otros 5 minutos a la subasta, hasta que no haya más ofertas la subasta termina.

```
Este es el código del tiempo 

 <?php
  if(isset($_POST["tiempo_limite"])){
    //arreglo para agregar bandera cuando la fecha concluya
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chihuahua'); 
    $indicador = array();
    //obtenemos fecha del servidor
    $fecha_servidor = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //declaramos el primer valor de fecha y tiempo
    $datetime1 = date_create($fecha_servidor);
    //declaramos el segundo valor de fecha y tiempo
    $datetime2 = date_create($_POST["tiempo_limite"]);
    //sacamos la diferencia entre las 2 fechas la limite de la bd y la del servidor
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    //le damos formato al intervalo que nos regreso la diferencia
    $fecha_restantes = "<i class='icons icon-clock'></i> Tiempo restante: ".$interval->format('%R%d días %H:%I:%s');
    $fecha_comparar = $interval->format('%R');
    if($fecha_comparar == '-'){
      echo "<b>Subasta cerrada</b>";
    ?>
      <script> document.getElementById('ofertar').disabled = true; </script>
    <?php
    }
    
    else{
      echo $fecha_restantes;
    }
  }
?>
```

y este código es cuando hacen una oferta

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('classes/puja.php');
    
    if (isset($_POST["ofertar"])){
        $puja = new Puja();
        //Si el usuario quiere ofertar por un producto

            if($_POST["oferta"]< $_POST["vmin"]){
                $_SESSION['msgError1'] = "<center>EL valor de oferta es menor al valor minimo.</center>";
            }
            else{               
                $puja->setIdsubasta($_POST["idsubasta"]);
                
                $rst = $puja->PujaMayor();
                $rst = $puja->PujasegundaMayor();
                $pujamayor = $rst['mayor'];
                $pujasegundamayor = $rst['segumayor'];
                $oferta = $_POST["oferta"];
                $envioart = $_POST["envioart"];
                $incremento = $_POST['incremento'];
    
                if($oferta <= $pujasegundamayor){
                    $_SESSION['msgError1'] = "<center>EL valor debe ser mayor al de la puja actual.</center>";
                }
                else{
                    $puja->setUsername($_SESSION["username"]);       
                    $puja->setValor($oferta); //POST CAJA TEXTO oferta
                    $reg = $puja->Registrar();
                    if($reg){   
                        try{
                            $nombres = $_SESSION['apellidos']." ".$_SESSION['nombres']; 
                            $_SESSION['msgSuccess1'] = "<center>Puja Enviada.</center>";
                            
                            $asunto = "Hola ".$nombres." has realizado una puja exitosa en la subasta del artículo: ".$envioart." con un valor de: ".$oferta;
                            mail($_SESSION['correo'],"Puja Realizada", $asunto) ;
                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                            $_SESSION['msgError1'] = 'Puja Exitosa, Correo no válido, no se notificó: '.$e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                    unset($reg); //libera el objeto PDOStatement           
                }
                unset($puja); //DESTRUCCION DEL OBJETO
            } 
              
        header('Location:' . getenv('HTTP_REFERER'));
    }
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar, muchas gracias.
**Entonces lo que ocupo que cuando falten 5 minutos para que finalice la subasta si alguien más oferta durante ese rango de minutos se sumen otros 5 minutos mas para que se alargue la subasta otros 5 minutos. Estoy trabajando en PHP y me gustaría saber cómo**